# Could not load file or assembly '2017-12-31 19-00 Copy of AjaxControlToolkit' or one of its dependencies

Tags: .net-assembly, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I have some issued in my exchange mail server 2013. After i login it's showing as below description. Please help me to solve this problem. Thanks.

### Server Error in '/ecp' Application.

> Could not load file or assembly '2017-12-31 19-00 Copy of
>   AjaxControlToolkit' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's
>   manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception
>   from HRESULT: 0x80131040)    Description: An unhandled exception
>   occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please
>   review the stack trace for more information about the error and where
>   it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file
>   or assembly '2017-12-31 19-00 Copy of AjaxControlToolkit' or one of
>   its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not
>   match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)
>
> Source Error:
>
> An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the
>   current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of
>   the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.
>
> Assembly Load Trace: The following information can be helpful to
>   determine why the assembly '2017-12-31 19-00 Copy of
>   AjaxControlToolkit' could not be loaded.
>
> WRN: Assembly binding logging is turned OFF. To enable assembly bind
>   failure logging, set the registry value
>   [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog] (DWORD) to 1. Note: There
>   is some performance penalty associated with assembly bind failure
>   logging. To turn this feature off, remove the registry value
>   [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog].
>
> Stack Trace:
>
> [FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly '2017-12-31 19-00
>   Copy of AjaxControlToolkit' or one of its dependencies. The located
>   assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference.
>   (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)]
>   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly._nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String
>   codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly locationHint,
>   StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean
>   throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean
>   suppressSecurityChecks) +0
>   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoadAssemblyName(AssemblyName
>   assemblyRef, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly reqAssembly,
>   StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean
>   throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean
>   suppressSecurityChecks) +210
>   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoad(String assemblyString,
>   Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr
>   pPrivHostBinder, Boolean forIntrospection) +242
>   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoad(String assemblyString,
>   Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean
>   forIntrospection) +17    System.Reflection.Assembly.Load(String
>   assemblyString) +35
>   System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAssemblyHelper(String
>   assemblyName, Boolean starDirective) +122
>
> [ConfigurationErrorsException: Could not load file or assembly
>   '2017-12-31 19-00 Copy of AjaxControlToolkit' or one of its
>   dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not
>   match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)]
>   System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAssemblyHelper(String
>   assemblyName, Boolean starDirective) +12761078
>   System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAllAssembliesFromAppDomainBinDirectory()
>   +503    System.Web.Configuration.AssemblyInfo.get_AssemblyInternal() +142    System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetReferencedAssemblies(CompilationSection
>   compConfig) +334
>   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CallPreStartInitMethods(String
>   preStartInitListPath) +203
>   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.ExecutePreAppStart() +152
>   System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.Initialize(ApplicationManager
>   appManager, IApplicationHost appHost, IConfigMapPathFactory
>   configMapPathFactory, HostingEnvironmentParameters hostingParameters,
>   PolicyLevel policyLevel, Exception appDomainCreationException) +1151
>
> [HttpException (0x80004005): Could not load file or assembly
>   '2017-12-31 19-00 Copy of AjaxControlToolkit' or one of its
>   dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not
>   match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)]
>   System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +12881540
>   System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext context)
>   +159    System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest
>   wr, HttpContext context) +12722601

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem has solved. I deleted the files name

- 2017-12-31 19-00 Copy of AjaxControlToolkit.dll
- 2017-12-31 19-00 Copy of Microsoft.Exchange.Management.ControlPanel.dll
- 2017-12-31 19-00 Copy of Microsoft.Exchange.Management.ControlPanel.OwaOptionStrings.dll
- 2017-12-31 19-00 Copy of Microsoft.Exchange.Management.ControlPanelMsg.dll
- 2017-12-31 19-00 Copy of Microsoft.Exchange.PowerShell.RbacHostingTools.dll
- 2017-12-31 19-00 Copy of Microsoft.Online.BOX.Shell.dll
- 2017-12-31 19-00 Copy of Microsoft.PowerShell.HostingTools.dll
- 2017-12-31 19-00 Copy of Web.config

From folder below:

D:\Microsoft\Exchange Server\V15\ClientAccess\ecp\bin

So it's work automatic. If you got error like that but display similar please try to delete (Copy to another folder, in case of problem we need recovery)that file from another folder.

Thanks!!!